# In Go, how can I state I want to match all kinds of space, including the non-breaking one?

Tags: regex, unicode, go, whitespace

I have to match a given pattern that looks like this :

```
Place *: *(.*)
```

In other words, I have a label, some spaces, a colon, some spaces, and the value I want.

However, I have in my data some places where spaces are not the usual `20` ASCII character, but non-breaking spaces (unicode character `\u00A0`). How can I match them ? I thought of using

```
Place\s*:\s*(.*)
```

but it does not seem to work on the `\u00A0` whitespace. Is this a bug of the regexp module or is this wanted behavior ? If it is the latter, how can I match all kinds of spaces without listing them all ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [re2 syntax](https://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/Syntax) does limit `\s` to `(≡ [\t\n\f\r ])`, which seems pretty much standard.

That might be the case where pre-processing the string, *before* using a regexp, is easier to do.
For example [`strings.Fields()`](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Fields) would split the string around spaces, [including unicode space runes](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/5868ce3519313dfa60dbc9192bf6b701b25bd4ca/src/strings/strings.go#L336-L341).

```
// Fields splits the string s around each instance of one or more consecutive white space
// characters, as defined by unicode.IsSpace, returning an array of substrings of s or an
// empty list if s contains only white space.
func Fields(s string) []string {
    return FieldsFunc(s, unicode.IsSpace)
}
```

That would take care of non-breakable space, since [`unicode.IsSpace()`](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsSpace)  reports whether the rune is a space character as defined by Unicode's White Space property; in the Latin-1 space this is:

```
'\t', '\n', '\v', '\f', '\r', ' ', U+0085 (NEL), U+00A0 (NBSP).
```

Comment: Great answer. I wasn't aware that `Fields` did this by default.